# How to follow a car with correct rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I am making a game where car will follow a user car. I am moving use car using keyboard keys it is working fine running on my game environment roads smoothly. To follow enemy car i am using nevMesh, it correctly following but the following car/enemey car rotation is not correct. I am surprise that how do i control it? or is there any other way to acheive this thing

Answer (score 2):

You can use "LookAt()" function to rotate your enemy cars.

```
public void LookTarget(){
    EnemyCarTransform.LookAt(UserCarTransform);
}
```

Make sure you use Transform property and call it everytime you move your enemy car.

Comment: Could you explain more what is exactly happening? Could you paste the enemy car code?

Comment: enemy is following using nevmesh i didnt write any code for follow

Comment: If you do not have code for enemy car were did you test "LookAt" function? On Update?

Comment: it is following the user car but the direction still not correct

Comment: Have you set updateRotation to true?  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent-updateRotation.html